# Oro PriceList business unit ownership

Tags: orocommerce

I have a requirement to configure ownership for `priceList` entities. To approach this I created a migration to add the required fields:

```
$this->extendExtension->addManyToOneRelation(
   $schema,
   $table,
   'organization',
   $organizationTable,
   'name',
   [
        'extend' => [
           'is_extend' => true,
           'owner' => ExtendScope::OWNER_SYSTEM,
           'without_default' => true,
        ]
   ]);

    $this->extendExtension->addManyToOneRelation(
        $schema,
        $table,
        'owner',
        $businessTable,
        'name',
        [
            'extend' => [
                'is_extend' => true,
                'owner' => ExtendScope::OWNER_SYSTEM,
                'without_default' => true,
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Then updated entity configuration information with:

```
$params = [
    "owner_type" => "BUSINESS_UNIT",
    "owner_field_name" => "owner",
    "owner_column_name" => "owner_id",
    "organization_field_name" => "organization",
    "organization_column_name" => "organization_id"
];
foreach($params as $code => $value) {
    $queries->addPostQuery(
        new UpdateEntityConfigEntityValueQuery(
            PriceList::class,
            'ownership',
            $code,
            $value
        )
    );
}
```

Migration processed without issues but for the data grid on the `priceList` index page error occurred.

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(o0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM oro_price_list o0_ WHERE o0_. = 1'

It looks like the data grid couldn't reach the organization name to handle the pagination query. Data grid unmodified grid from ORO 4.1 EE

Comment: Hi Artoa, How have you updated the entity configuration information?

Comment: Hi Andrey, I updated the description with additional information regarding updating configuration.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the ownership config. You can check its state with the command:
`php bin/console oro:entity-config:debug "Oro\Bundle\PricingBundle\Entity\PriceList" organization -eprod`

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine if ownership configuration updated via `SetOwnershipTypeQuery` intead of `UpdateEntityConfigEntityValueQuery`

```
$queries->addQuery(
    new SetOwnershipTypeQuery(
        PriceList::class,
        [
            'owner_type' => 'BUSINESS_UNIT',
            'owner_field_name' => 'owner',
            'owner_column_name' => 'owner_id',
            'organization_field_name' => 'organization',
            'organization_column_name' => 'organization_id'
        ]
    )
);
```